# How can I reset the powershell colors

Tags: powershell, colors

I changed the colors of the powershell and now I can't change the color of the input text, is always **yellow**.

I changed the color of the background and the color of the text

[image: changing colors]

The color of the background changed correctly but in the display text the color still is yellow.

[image: changed]

Can I do something to reset the colors?

Comment: `Remove-Module PSReadline`

Comment: @PetSerAl maybe explain why that (probably) would work

Comment: When a remove the module work fine, but when I start a new shell the color still be yellow

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen As I can judge from image, yellow text come from `PSReadline` module coloring user input. If you unload `PSReadline` module, then it will stop doing so, but you will lose all benefits from `PSReadline`. Of course, you could also use `Set-PSReadlineOption` to change colors of different tokens.

Answer (score 131):

**Method 1: Command in CLI**

This CLI resets the console colours (e.g. BackgroundColor): (Paste in the PowerShell console) (However, be aware that this reset the color, but not reset the theme previously choosed)

```
[Console]::ResetColor()
```

My CLI Logs just for reference:

```
PowerShell 7.3.3
PS C:\Users\betim> [Console]::ResetColor()
PS C:\Users\betim>
```

**Method 2: PowerShell Settings**

Go to Windows Terminal, then settings of PowerShell, then choose the theme, or anything you want to change actually. I like theme "Campbell"

BTW, you can download the latest powershell separately. In this example I am using version 7.3.3

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you running in powershell or default cmd? Can u paste the error? @bucky

Comment: powershell as admin. there is no error, it just does not reset the colors to default. anyway, i googled the rgb codes of the default colors and changed it back manually. (1,36,86) for background and (255,255,255) foreground (text)

Comment: @DrewChapin has the right answer, when I try to visit PowerShell by a different shortcut or directly, my previously chosen color preferences for PowerShell aren't used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49197154/1507941

Comment: Great, Wasn't aware of Windows Terminal so please hyperlink the [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install). Works like charm!

Answer (score 17):

I realize this is an old question, but I found it in Google and have another solution.

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -ForegroundColor Black
```

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt560335.aspx)

This will change the input text to black. The available color choices are as follows:

- Black
- DarkBlue
- DarkGreen
- DarkCyan
- DarkRed
- DarkMagent
- DarkYellow
- Gray
- DarkGray
- Blue
- Green
- Cyan
- Red
- Magenta
- Yellow
- White

You can make this persist by adding it to your profile. It's enough to append the command to the end of the file.

In my case the profile is in: `C:\Users\Billy\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

To get the location of your PS profile type:

```
$profile
```

If this file doesn't exist, you can create it with:

```
New-item –type file –force $profile
```

([source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff461033.aspx))

To see the current settings in your profile, use:

```
Get-PSReadlineOption
```

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/get-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-5.1))

Comment: I was struggling with yellow commands on a white background in my PowerShell. This answer got me on the right direction. While the 'Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Command -ForegroundColor Black' command did not work for me, I found this page https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7#example-4--set-multiple-color-options and adding the -colors options to the PowerShell profile file helped me regain control of my PowerShell colors. This blog post was also helpful: https://beebom.com/how-change-powershell-color-scheme-windows-10/

Answer (score 12):

The colors you see by right clicking on the title bar and clicking on Properties are actually stored in the shortcut file itself in the `ExtraData` section. You can just delete shortcut and recreate it, or you can use a hex editor to change the values. Outside of that, there is not "reset" feature. This is also true for the normal command prompt.

[image: 010 Editor Screenshot]

Answer (score 11):

## Answer

With respect to the original question, the yellow text is intentional. It is syntax coloring from the [PSReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline?view=powershell-6) module. This coloring is the (new) default for Windows PowerShell.

As [PetSerAl mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859498/how-can-i-reset-the-powershell-colors#comment55483585_33859498), `Remove-Module PSReadline` will remove the highlighting for that session. If you want to permanently remove PSReadLine then modify your [PowerShell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6) with these PowerShell commands:

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE)) {
  New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force
}
Add-Content $PROFILE "`nRemove-Module PSReadline"
```

If you want to change the syntax coloring, follow the documentation for [Set-PSReadLineOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-6). Specifically, look at parameters with "color" in their name. And make sure to set the version in the documentation to match [your PowerShell version](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/039fb498-9c1a-4bca-bfd9-3b2cdfd87eb9/how-to-find-out-what-version-of-powershell-i-have). (One exception is Windows 10 version 1809 and later which [uses the PowerShell 6.0 syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/?view=powershell-6).)

[image: Where to change the PowerShell version on the Microsoft documentation Web site.]

#### Example

For example, if you wanted to change the command text color from yellow to magenta then (using the PowerShell 6 syntax) you could enter the following into a PowerShell:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{
"Command" = [ConsoleColor]::Magenta
}
```

Keep in mind this is temporary and would have to be added to your PowerShell profile to become permanent.

---

## Fixing Shortcut Colors

If, on the other hand, you saw the shortcut properties screen capture in the original question and thought, "Hey, I screwed up my shortcut colors," then this answer is for you.

As [Drew Chapin points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49197154/2674513), an easy solution to fix that issue is to recreate the shortcut. But if you just create a new shortcut and point it to powershell.exe, you'll get a black and white shell.

[image: PowerShell in black and white.]

If you want the nice blue and white shell, you'll have to do something else.

[image: PowerShell with default blue color.]

Before you create new shortcuts, it is a good idea to clear out the ones causing the problem. If you have them pinned somewhere and are not sure where the actual shortcut file is located then below are some common locations. Enter these paths into the File Explorer address bar, one at a time, and poke around. In some instances, I give the path to a parent folder and suggest that you use the search function in File Explorer to search for "powershell" in the subfolders:

```
shell:Common Desktop
shell:Common Start Menu    search for "powershell"
shell:Common Startup
shell:Quick Launch
shell:Start Menu           search for "powershell"
shell:Startup
shell:User Pinned          search for "powershell"
```

[image: Typing a shell command into the File Explorer address bar.]

[image: Searching for "powershell" in a parent folder.]

### Creating New PowerShell Shortcuts

Coming back to fresh shortcuts, the do-it-yourself solution is to create a new Windows user and to copy the PowerShell shortcuts from their start menu. You can find the shortcuts by opening File Explorer and navigating to:

```
shell:Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell
```

If you don't want to go through the trouble of creating a new user or are unable to do so, I created a PowerShell script that will create the shortcuts for you. [Change directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-6#examples) to where you want the shortcuts created. Then either paste the following commands in a PowerShell or save and execute them as a .ps1 file. Remember that the shortcuts will be created in the [current working directory](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/currentd.htm).

#### Example

1. Open PowerShell.
2. Change directory to the PowerShell folder in the Start Menu.

```
set-location "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell"
```

3. Remove the existing shortcuts (if they're giving you problems).

```
remove-item .\*.lnk -whatif
```

4. Run the script below.

```
# Base64-encoded PowerShell .lnk files from a new Windows user profile. 
# Windows 10.0.17763.615 en-US

$windowsPowerShellLnk = @"
TAAAAAEUAgAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAEbfAgAAIAAAAJuvlrfNas0Bm6+Wt81qzQGAHQKo3WrNAQDwBgAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPEBFAAfUOBP0CDqOmkQotgIACswMJ0ZAC9DOlwAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUgAxAAAAAADHQgKwMABXaW5kb3dzADwACAAEAO+++kDALMdCArAqAAAAHxAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAAAAWAFYAMQAAAAAAx0JdBTAAU3lzdG
VtMzIAAD4ACAAEAO+++kDBLMdCXQUqAAAAChgAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtADMAMgAAABgAaAAxAAAAAAD6QKBBEABXSU5ET1d+MQAAUAAIAAQA7776QKBB+kCgQSoAAAC
HHQAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBQAG8AdwBlAHIAUwBoAGUAbABsAAAAGABKADEAAAAAALhC660UAHYxLjAAADYACAAEAO+++kCgQbhC660qAAAAiB0AAAAAAQAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAHYAMQAuADAAAAAUAGgAMgAA8AYA+kCaGiAAcG93ZXJzaGVsbC5leGUAAEoACAAEAO+++kBXC/pAVwsqAAAA//kAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHAAbwB3AGUAcgBzAGgAZQBsA
GwALgBlAHgAZQAAAB4AAABuAAAAHAAAAAEAAAAcAAAAMwAAAAAAAABtAAAAFwAAAAMAAABzLe50EAAAAE9TRGlzawBDOlxXaW5kb3dzXFN5c3RlbTMyXFdpbmRvd3NQb3dlclNoZWxsXHYxLjBccG
93ZXJzaGVsbC5leGUAAC4AUABlAHIAZgBvAHIAbQBzACAAbwBiAGoAZQBjAHQALQBiAGEAcwBlAGQAIAAoAGMAbwBtAG0AYQBuAGQALQBsAGkAbgBlACkAIABmAHUAbgBjAHQAaQBvAG4AcwA/AC4
ALgBcAC4ALgBcAC4ALgBcAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAXABTAHkAcwB0AGUAbQAzADIAXABXAGkAbgBkAG8AdwBzAFAAbwB3AGUAcgBTAGgAZQBsAGwAXAB2ADEALgAwAFwAcABvAHcAZQByAHMAaABl
AGwAbAAuAGUAeABlABUAJQBIAE8ATQBFAEQAUgBJAFYARQAlACUASABPAE0ARQBQAEEAVABIACUAOwAlAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAFIAbwBvAHQAJQBcAHMAeQBzAHQAZQBtADMAMgBcAFcAaQBuAGQAb
wB3AHMAUABvAHcAZQByAFMAaABlAGwAbABcAHYAMQAuADAAXABwAG8AdwBlAHIAcwBoAGUAbABsAC4AZQB4AGUAFAMAAAEAAKAlU3lzdGVtUm9vdCVcc3lzdGVtMzJcV2luZG93c1Bvd2VyU2hlbG
xcdjEuMFxwb3dlcnNoZWxsLmV4ZQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACUA
UwB5AHMAdABlAG0AUgBvAG8AdAAlAFwAcwB5AHMAdABlAG0AMwAyAFwAVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBQAG8AdwBlAHIAUwBoAGUAbABsAFwAdgAxAC4AMABcAHAAbwB3AGUAcgBzAGgAZQBsAGwALgBlA
HgAZQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAABQAAoCUAAADVAAAAHAAAAAsAAKB3TsEa5wJdTrdELrGuUZi31
QAAAGAAAAADAACgWAAAAAAAAABsZWVob2xtMTYAAAAAAAAAmpqyu7ZVLUqI6zLq13xnQNkHI1xpM+IRvnAAHMQt9AuamrK7tlUtSojrMurXfGdA2QcjXGkz4hG+cAAcxC30C8wAAAACAACgVgDzAH
gAuAt4ADIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOADYAAACQAQAAQwBvAG4AcwBvAGwAYQBzAAAAbgBzAG8AbABlAAAA/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/hkAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAEAAAA
BAAAAMgAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAgAAAAICAAIAAAAABJFYA7u3wAMDAwACAgIAAAAD/AAD/AAAA//8A/wAAAP8A/wD//wAA////AB8BAAAJAACgkQAAADFTUFPiilhGvEw4Q7v8E5MmmG3O
dQAAAAQAAAAAHwAAADIAAABTAC0AMQAtADUALQAyADEALQAyADEAMgA3ADUAMgAxADEAOAA0AC0AMQA2ADAANAAwADEAMgA5ADIAMAAtADEAOAA4ADcAOQAyADcANQAyADcALQAxADEAOAAwADYAN
AAzAAAAAAAAAIIAAAAxU1BTBwZXDJYD3kOdYeMh199QJhEAAAADAAAAAAsAAAD//wAAEQAAAAEAAAAACwAAAP//AAARAAAAAgAAAAALAAAA//8AABEAAAAEAAAAAAsAAAAAAAAAEQAAAAYAAAAAAg
AAAP8AAAARAAAABQAAAAALAAAA//8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
"@


$WindowsPowerShellISE = @"
TAAAAAEUAgAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAEbUAwACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEEAQAAlAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAFIAbwBvAHQAJQBcAHMAeQBzA
HQAZQBtADMAMgBcAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAUABvAHcAZQByAFMAaABlAGwAbABcAHYAMQAuADAAXABwAG8AdwBlAHIAcwBoAGUAbABsAC4AZQB4AGUALAAtADEAMQAzABUAJQBIAE8ATQBFAEQAUg
BJAFYARQAlACUASABPAE0ARQBQAEEAVABIACUAPwAlAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAFIAbwBvAHQAJQBcAHMAeQBzAHQAZQBtADMAMgBcAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAUABvAHcAZQByAFMAaABlAGwAbABcAHY
AMQAuADAAXABwAG8AdwBlAHIAcwBoAGUAbABsAF8AaQBzAGUALgBlAHgAZQBmAAAACQAAoC0AAAAxU1BT4opYRrxMOEO7/BOTJphtzhEAAAAAAAAAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0AAAAxU1BTVShMn3mf
OUuo0OHULeHV8xEAAAASAAAAABMAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAwAAAQAAoCV3aW5kaXIlXHN5c3RlbTMyXFdpbmRvd3NQb3dlclNoZWxsXHYxLjBcUG93ZXJTaGVsbF9JU0UuZXhlAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJQB3AGkAbgBkAGkAcgAlAFwAcwB5AHMAdABlAG0AMwA
yAFwAVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBQAG8AdwBlAHIAUwBoAGUAbABsAFwAdgAxAC4AMABcAFAAbwB3AGUAcgBTAGgAZQBsAGwAXwBJAFMARQAuAGUAeABlAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
"@


$WindowsPowerShellx86 = @"
TAAAAAEUAgAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAEbfAgAAIAAAAJuvlrfNas0Bm6+Wt81qzQGAHQKo3WrNAQDwBgAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPEBFAAfUOBP0CDqOmkQotgIACswMJ0ZAC9DOlwAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUgAxAAAAAADHQgKwMABXaW5kb3dzADwACAAEAO+++kDALMdCArAqAAAAHxAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAAAAWAFYAMQAAAAAAuELmrRAAU3lzV0
9XNjQAAD4ACAAEAO+++kDBLLhC5q0qAAAAiRwAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFMAeQBzAFcATwBXADYANAAAABgAaAAxAAAAAAD6QKBBEABXSU5ET1d+MQAAUAAIAAQA7776QKBB+kCgQSoAAAC
HHQAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBQAG8AdwBlAHIAUwBoAGUAbABsAAAAGABKADEAAAAAALhC660UAHYxLjAAADYACAAEAO+++kCgQbhC660qAAAAiB0AAAAAAQAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAHYAMQAuADAAAAAUAGgAMgAA8AYA+kCaGiAAcG93ZXJzaGVsbC5leGUAAEoACAAEAO+++kBXC/pAVwsqAAAA//kAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHAAbwB3AGUAcgBzAGgAZQBsA
GwALgBlAHgAZQAAAB4AAABuAAAAHAAAAAEAAAAcAAAAMwAAAAAAAABtAAAAFwAAAAMAAABzLe50EAAAAE9TRGlzawBDOlxXaW5kb3dzXFN5c1dPVzY0XFdpbmRvd3NQb3dlclNoZWxsXHYxLjBccG
93ZXJzaGVsbC5leGUAAC4AUABlAHIAZgBvAHIAbQBzACAAbwBiAGoAZQBjAHQALQBiAGEAcwBlAGQAIAAoAGMAbwBtAG0AYQBuAGQALQBsAGkAbgBlACkAIABmAHUAbgBjAHQAaQBvAG4AcwA/AC4
ALgBcAC4ALgBcAC4ALgBcAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAXABTAHkAcwBXAE8AVwA2ADQAXABXAGkAbgBkAG8AdwBzAFAAbwB3AGUAcgBTAGgAZQBsAGwAXAB2ADEALgAwAFwAcABvAHcAZQByAHMAaABl
AGwAbAAuAGUAeABlABUAJQBIAE8ATQBFAEQAUgBJAFYARQAlACUASABPAE0ARQBQAEEAVABIACUAOwAlAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAFIAbwBvAHQAJQBcAHMAeQBzAHcAbwB3ADYANABcAFcAaQBuAGQAb
wB3AHMAUABvAHcAZQByAFMAaABlAGwAbABcAHYAMQAuADAAXABwAG8AdwBlAHIAcwBoAGUAbABsAC4AZQB4AGUAFAMAAAEAAKAlU3lzdGVtUm9vdCVcc3lzd293NjRcV2luZG93c1Bvd2VyU2hlbG
xcdjEuMFxwb3dlcnNoZWxsLmV4ZQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACUA
UwB5AHMAdABlAG0AUgBvAG8AdAAlAFwAcwB5AHMAdwBvAHcANgA0AFwAVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBQAG8AdwBlAHIAUwBoAGUAbABsAFwAdgAxAC4AMABcAHAAbwB3AGUAcgBzAGgAZQBsAGwALgBlA
HgAZQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAABQAAoCkAAADVAAAAHAAAAAsAAKCwMVLW8bJXSKTOqOfG6n0n1
QAAAGAAAAADAACgWAAAAAAAAABsZWVob2xtMTYAAAAAAAAAmpqyu7ZVLUqI6zLq13xnQNkHI1xpM+IRvnAAHMQt9AuamrK7tlUtSojrMurXfGdA2QcjXGkz4hG+cAAcxC30C8wAAAACAACgVgDzAH
gAuAt4ADIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOADYAAACQAQAAQwBvAG4AcwBvAGwAYQBzAAAAbgBzAG8AbABlAAAA/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/v7+/hkAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAEAAAA
BAAAAMgAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAgAAAAICAAIAAAAABJFYA7u3wAMDAwACAgIAAAAD/AAD/AAAA//8A/wAAAP8A/wD//wAA////AB8BAAAJAACgkQAAADFTUFPiilhGvEw4Q7v8E5MmmG3O
dQAAAAQAAAAAHwAAADIAAABTAC0AMQAtADUALQAyADEALQAyADEAMgA3ADUAMgAxADEAOAA0AC0AMQA2ADAANAAwADEAMgA5ADIAMAAtADEAOAA4ADcAOQAyADcANQAyADcALQAxADEAOAAwADYAN
AAzAAAAAAAAAIIAAAAxU1BTBwZXDJYD3kOdYeMh199QJhEAAAADAAAAAAsAAAD//wAAEQAAAAEAAAAACwAAAP//AAARAAAAAgAAAAALAAAA//8AABEAAAAEAAAAAAsAAAAAAAAAEQAAAAYAAAAAAg
AAAP8AAAARAAAABQAAAAALAAAA//8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
"@


$WindowsPowerShellISEx86 = @"
TAAAAAEUAgAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAEbUAwACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEEAQAAlAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAFIAbwBvAHQAJQBcAHMAeQBzA
HQAZQBtADMAMgBcAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAUABvAHcAZQByAFMAaABlAGwAbABcAHYAMQAuADAAXABwAG8AdwBlAHIAcwBoAGUAbABsAC4AZQB4AGUALAAtADEAMQAzABUAJQBIAE8ATQBFAEQAUg
BJAFYARQAlACUASABPAE0ARQBQAEEAVABIACUAPwAlAFMAeQBzAHQAZQBtAFIAbwBvAHQAJQBcAHMAeQBzAHQAZQBtADMAMgBcAFcAaQBuAGQAbwB3AHMAUABvAHcAZQByAFMAaABlAGwAbABcAHY
AMQAuADAAXABwAG8AdwBlAHIAcwBoAGUAbABsAF8AaQBzAGUALgBlAHgAZQBmAAAACQAAoC0AAAAxU1BT4opYRrxMOEO7/BOTJphtzhEAAAAAAAAAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0AAAAxU1BTVShMn3mf
OUuo0OHULeHV8xEAAAASAAAAABMAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAwAAAQAAoCV3aW5kaXIlXHN5c3dvdzY0XFdpbmRvd3NQb3dlclNoZWxsXHYxLjBcUG93ZXJTaGVsbF9JU0UuZXhlAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJQB3AGkAbgBkAGkAcgAlAFwAcwB5AHMAdwBvAHcANgA
0AFwAVwBpAG4AZABvAHcAcwBQAG8AdwBlAHIAUwBoAGUAbABsAFwAdgAxAC4AMABcAFAAbwB3AGUAcgBTAGgAZQBsAGwAXwBJAFMARQAuAGUAeABlAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
"@


# Decode and save to file.  

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$pwd\Windows PowerShell.lnk",           ([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($windowsPowerShellLnk)))
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$pwd\Windows PowerShell ISE.lnk",       ([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($WindowsPowerShellISE)))
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$pwd\Windows PowerShell (x86).lnk",     ([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($WindowsPowerShellx86)))
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$pwd\Windows PowerShell ISE (x86).lnk", ([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($WindowsPowerShellISEx86)))

# Trailing comment as a selection-aid for Stack Overflow readers.
```

---

Also, I have some commentary on the thread to date.

The answers that set out to reset the PSReadLine colors assume that those colors have been permanently set to non-defaults. That is unlikely because you would have to make a change to your PowerShell profile. And you would know if you changed your profile.

The other problem here is that *yellow* is the intended color for commands in the default PSReadLine scheme. So any reset would only give the original poster the same yellow text.

With respect to non-default colors, an easy test is to close and reopen PowerShell. If, when typing a command, the text is yellow then you're probably OK; whatever was troubling you was limited to that PowerShell session and is now gone.

If you want to check your PowerShell profile for any (permanent) [Set-PSReadLineOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-6) commands then enter

```
notepad $profile
```

into PowerShell and browse through the text file that opens. If you receive an error then you don't have a profile, (and it can't be the problem).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions.  This is the only way that I have found to reset the Powershell color scheme.

Comment: I'm glad this helped you. You might also like [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701). The one downside to Terminal is that it is not possible to disable right-click paste.

Comment: Finally, something that WORKS!  That PSReadline feature is a nightmare.  They should not be allowing users to edit console colors and then have a separate color setting that makes text invisible.

Comment: Thank you so much. This should be marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:** as pointed out by @dhobbs in the comments, this is no longer an option in PowerShell 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PSReadline/Set-PSReadlineOption?view=powershell-6.

Resetting the PowerShell console colors to their defaults can be done with the following command:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -ResetTokenColors
```

Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption

Add the line to your PowerShell profile to make it have the command run each time a PowerShell console is opened. To see the location of your PowerShell profile, from a PowerShell console type:

```
$profile
```

Comment: This didn't work for me (windows 10), but the answer from Xin did it

Comment: This doesn't work for Powershell 6, which doesn't have the `-ResetTokenColors` parameter.

Answer (score 6):

Stolen from Xin, but I cannot comment so you're going to have to accept that

```
[Console]::ResetColor()
```

then clear the screen to let the change take effect.

```
clear
```

I think that was the problem bucky was having with the previous answer.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 4):

I found this worked.  It's the answer from user 577111 I think.  We need to put all this into PS.

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{
### Use a ConsoleColor enum 
"Error" = [ConsoleColor]::DarkRed
### 24 bit color escape sequence 
"String" = "$([char]0x1b)[38;5;100m"
### RGB value 
"Command" = "#8181f7" }
```

Comment: Please format your code to improve the readability of your answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I have tried to format it and failed.  Tried to get all the code into one code block instead of just that one line.  But I couldn't do it.

The link NOhs provided took me to a page about formatting and didn't mention code.

Answer (score 3):

Is it the ISE you are referring to? If so select Tools > Options and you will see the option to change background and foreground colour. From here you can select "Restore Defaults"

Answer (score 2):

You can backup colors using this facility.

https://github.com/lukesampson/concfg/blob/master/README.md

It provides wonderful preset settings that work perfectly.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: `concfg` is probably the easiest option I've seen here. Install it using the instructions in the README. The program can reset colors to default with `concfg import powershell-default`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the MS page linked to in one of the above answers worked for me just now, today,  june 2019

[ms fix for powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PSReadline/Set-PSReadlineOption?view=powershell-6)

I simply pasted their first suggestion - this - into powershell and it seems okay now:

---

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{
    #Use a ConsoleColor enum
    "Error"   = [ConsoleColor]::DarkRed

    #24 bit color escape sequence
    "String"  = "$([char]0x1b)[38;5;100m"

    #RGB value
    "Command" = "#8181f7"
}
```

though I'm not 100% sure because the white background I set is still there.  But the yellow is gone, that's for sure.

This is a later edit.  I've come back and tried to put all that into a code block instead of just the first line but I can't figure  out how to do it.

Point is you must put all the code between the curly braces in and the #tagged lines are comments.  Unfortunately the comments and code are all on the same line and I can't fix it.  The comment finishes where the " " text begins.

Would have been simpler if I'd taken the comments out I guess.  Anyway.. June 2019, this is the only technique that worked for me.

p.s.  I now find the fix doesn't work after closing down.  When I restart I have to do it again.

Comment: It is possible to place this code snipped in the `$profile` file (similar to `~/.bashrc`)