# My powershell colours are messed up, and is very unreadable. Is there a way I can reset everything to the defaults?

Tags: powershell

All the error messages are highlighted in red, and the the highlighted text has the same color as the highlight.

**The Color Errors**:

[image: The color errors]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reset the powershell colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859498/how-can-i-reset-the-powershell-colors)

Comment: It didn't work. The problem still persists. I've seen this already. Is there a way I can just reset the whole thing?

Comment: Did you try all 5 answers? Or just set the colors manually if you must :(

Comment: https://winsmarts.com/fix-powershell-error-colors-14059255cd0 <-this link talks about the file that modifies error colors.

Comment: to make the file try `new-item -path $profile -force -itemtype file`

Comment: I tried everything. I manually reset all the colors over and over again.

Comment: Well I tired your solution Robert. I'm not sure what i'm supposed to do with it, It's empty.

Comment: sorry for the late response, with that file you can edit in colors of your own choosing. The link shows some examples.  Here are more examples of how to customize it https://mcpmag.com/articles/2011/06/06/color-my-powershell-world.aspx